# Trigger to throw or rethrow an error in filter function

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2

What could be the trigger that makes the filter function `throws` or `rethrows` an error?
`someArray.filter(includeElement: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool )`

Answer (score 3):

The "trigger" is the presence of some code inside the closure that can throw an error, i.e. there is a `try` inside the closure.

The `filter` method is defined to not only accept closures that might throw an error, but also rethrow any errors thrown by its closure. So, if you call `filter` with closure that throws an error (i.e. the closure has a `try` statement), you can then wrap the whole `filter` in its own `do`-`try`-`catch` pattern to gracefully handle any errors its closures may throw.

```
do {
    let result = array.filter {
        // some code with `try` in it here
        return success
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

For example, let's imagine you had some `Fraction` type that throws some custom `Error` when you try to `calculateValue` when the denominator is zero.

```
enum MathError: Error {
    case divideByZero
}

struct Fraction {
    let numerator: Int
    let denominator: Int

    func calculateValue() throws -> Double {
        if denominator == 0 {
            throw MathError.divideByZero
        }

        return Double(numerator) / Double(denominator)
    }
}
```

You can then do something like:

```
let fractions = [
    Fraction(numerator: 1, denominator: 3),
    Fraction(numerator: 5, denominator: 7),
    Fraction(numerator: 4, denominator: 0)
]

do {
    let biggerThanOneHalf = try fractions.filter {
        try $0.calculateValue() > 0.5
    }
    print(biggerThanOneHalf)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

Clearly, if the closure that you supplied to `filter` doesn't throw any errors (i.e. there is no `try` in the closure), then you do not have to worry about `filter` rethrowing anything, and no `do`-`catch` block is simply not needed at all:

```
let numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

let evenNumbers = numbers.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
```

---

For Swift 2 rendition, see previous [revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33273900/5).

Comment: Okay then, can you explain how to use exactly the second function, shown on [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvjI5.png)

Comment: It depends. Are you doing something in your closure that throws errors? Then it's like above where you just wrap it in the `do`-`catch` block and use `try` inside the `filter` closure. But if you're not doing anything that throws errors (i.e. you're not using `try` inside the closure), then none of that `do`-`catch` stuff is needed and it's just `let result = array.filter { ... }`.